Getting fork exception in maven gatling plugin
I am getting a fork exception in the Maven Gatling plugin. How do I handle this exception?
I use the Gatling Maven plugin to run my performance tests from karate scripts.
Karate version: 1.4.1
Gatling Maven plugin: 4.3.4


please try to follow stack overflow guidelines, else I don't think you would get any help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I was able to solve this issue by tweaking the thread-pool-size in gatling-akka.conf file.

A lot depends on the available CPU and memory on the system. Tweaking the thread counts will help you find the right match for your performance testing.
